# Can not do math with structures in ColdFusion

Tags: data-structures, coldfusion

I am looping over a list and want to create a struct of struct if a struct key doesn't exist yet, but if it does exist, I want to only update one of the keys with a new value by adding something to the existing value of that key. It will not do that and I don't know why.

Here's the code:

```
<cfloop list="#recipeItemList#" index="ril">
    <cfset thisrecipe = entityLoadByPK("recipes", #ril#)>

    <cfloop array="#thisrecipe.getrecipeitem()#" index="recipeItems">

        <cfif recipeItems.hasrawMaterial_id()>
            <cfset theitem = entityLoadByPK("rawMaterials", recipeItems.getrawMaterial_id().getid())>

            <cfinvoke method="getPrepByDate" component="/FEcomponents.production" returnvariable="makeAmount">
                <cfinvokeargument name="recipe_id" value="#ril#">
                <cfinvokeargument name="delivery_date" value="#delivery_date#">
            </cfinvoke>

            <cfset thisRecipeYield = #thisRecipe.getYield()#>

            <cfif thisRecipeYield neq 0>
                <cfset recipeRatio = makeAmount / thisRecipeYield>
            </cfif>

            <cfset thisQuantity = recipeRatio * #recipeItems.getitemQuantity()#>

            <cfif structKeyExists(outerstruct, '#theitem.getid()#')>

                <!--- we must add this quantity to the existing key, not create a new one --->
                <cfset addthis = #outerstruct[theitem.getid()].totalToGet# + #thisQuantity#>

                <cfset structInsert(outerstruct[theitem.getid()],'totalToGet', #addthis#,true)>

                <!--- this is just to for testing to see if the value has changed, and it does not the 'addthis' value is always the latest value in the loop--->
                #outerstruct[theitem.getid()].totalToGet# + #thisquantity# = #addthis# <BR>
            <cfelse>
                <!--- create a new struct --->
                <cfset outerstruct[theitem.getid()] = structnew()>
                <cfset outerstruct[theitem.getid()].rawMaterialid = #theitem.getid()#>
                <cfset outerstruct[theitem.getid()].rawMaterialName = #theItem.getName()#>
                <cfset outerstruct[theitem.getid()].totalToGet = #thisQuantity#>
                <cfset outerstruct[theitem.getid()].uom = #theItem.getUOM().getname()#>
            </cfif>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

What am I doing wrong.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want, I removed a few of the extra pound signs and changed the way you are updating the struct key. I'm sorry I am unable to run the code but I believe this should work.

```
<cfloop list="#recipeItemList#" index="ril">
<cfset thisrecipe = entityLoadByPK("recipes", #ril#)>

<cfloop array="#thisrecipe.getrecipeitem()#" index="recipeItems">

    <cfif recipeItems.hasrawMaterial_id()>
        <cfset theitem = entityLoadByPK("rawMaterials", recipeItems.getrawMaterial_id().getid())>

        <cfinvoke method="getPrepByDate" component="/FEcomponents.production" returnvariable="makeAmount">
            <cfinvokeargument name="recipe_id" value="#ril#">
            <cfinvokeargument name="delivery_date" value="#delivery_date#">
        </cfinvoke>

        <cfset thisRecipeYield = thisRecipe.getYield()>
        <cfset thisQuantity = recipeItems.getitemQuantity()>

        <cfif thisRecipeYield neq 0>
            <cfset recipeRatio = makeAmount / thisRecipeYield>
            <cfset thisQuantity *= recipeRatio>
        </cfif>

        <cfif structKeyExists(outerstruct, theitem.getid())>
            <!--- we must add this quantity to the existing key, not create a new one --->
            <cfset outerstruct[theitem.getid()].totalToGet += thisQuantity>
        <cfelse>
            <!--- create a new struct --->
            <cfset outerstruct[theitem.getid()] = structnew()>
            <cfset outerstruct[theitem.getid()].rawMaterialid = theitem.getid()>
            <cfset outerstruct[theitem.getid()].rawMaterialName = theItem.getName()>
            <cfset outerstruct[theitem.getid()].totalToGet = thisQuantity>
            <cfset outerstruct[theitem.getid()].uom = theItem.getUOM().getname()>
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.